# Why git lfs checkout is 60 times slower than git lfs fetch?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have been getting very slow clone times with git LFS projects on my PC running Windows 7. When I do a normal clone or checkout it takes around 20 minutes to download just 60 MB of LFS objects. After removing the LFS objects, `rm -rf .git/lfs/*` if I run `git lfs fetch` for the  same repo in the same network on the exact same machine the same 60 MB of LFS objects are downloaded in 20 **seconds**, this is 60 times faster.

Is there something that I am missing here?

I cannot understand what is going on. Is there a way to make git be more verbose than just the `--verbose` flag?

Edit: On my laptop I clone this entire repo in 1 minute. So this issue is only isolated to my PC.

Comment: git lfs is more large file storage, I don't see 60 MB is large for the git repo. if you do simple git checkout without that extension then it will be much faster.  Is your one file size if 60MB?

Comment: Try having *just* 60 MB of binaries in a repo with active development and change those binaries every day and then tell me how long it takes to clone your repo.

Comment: it depends on the client and the protocol you use. If you use github that will complain if the file is bigger than 50mb but you don't have that issue if you use ssh.

Comment: I think that using git checkout or git pull, LFS tries to download the files one at a time, but when using git lfs fetch, it downloads multiple files at once.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Pere it's been a while but in my case it turned out to be a DNS issue. I'm not sure why/how but as far as I remember for some reason during a normal clone git resolves the DNS once for every LFS object, whereas when you run `git lfs fetch` it seems to cache the DNS resolution. Try using strace and see where it's being blocked. I remember in my case it was blocked on a read call.